# Wordpress posts not loaded when login as non admin? (custom theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, infinite-scroll

I am building a website that able user to posts an article using wordpress (I build my own theme). And in home page, the user will view posts by user that followed by it (like twitter timeline). I use infinite scroll based on jQuery to replace the pagination.

Everything is fine and works if I login as admin, the problem is when I login as another privilege such as author. The page will only load first page. And another page will not loaded.

This is my code in function.php :

```
    //-----------------Infinite Scroll-------------------------------

/*
 * initial posts dispaly
 */
function script_load_more($args = array()) {
    //initial posts load
    echo '<div id="ajax-primary" class="content-area">';
        echo '<div id="ajax-content" class="content-area">';
            ajax_script_load_more($args);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<center><a href="#" id="loadMore"  data-page="1" data-url="'.admin_url("admin-ajax.php").'" ></a></center>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/*
 * create short code.
 */
add_shortcode('ajax_posts', 'script_load_more');

/*
 * load more script call back
 */

function ajax_script_load_more($args) {
    //init ajax
    $ajax = false;
    //check ajax call or not
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $ajax = true;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $cekpost = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT post_author FROM  ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_author = ".get_current_user_id()." AND post_status='publish'");
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT follow FROM  ".$wpdb->prefix."follow WHERE user = ".get_current_user_id());
    if (sizeof($cekpost)>0 OR sizeof($result)>0){

        //number of posts per page default
        $num =5;
        //page number
        $paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;

        $jumlah=count($result);;
        $i=0;
        $following = get_current_user_id();

        foreach ( $result as $hasil )
        {
            $i++;
            //if ($i<$jumlah){
                $following=$following.",".$hasil->follow;
                //$following=$following.",";
            //}
        }

        //echo $following;
        if ($following!=null){
            echo "inside following".get_current_user_id();
            //args
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                 //'author' => $following,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' =>$num,
                'paged'=>$paged
            );
            //query
            $query = new WP_Query($args);

            //var_dump($query);
            //check
            if ($query->have_posts()):
                //loop articles
                while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                    include 'ajax-content.php';
                    //reset post data
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                endwhile;
            endif;
        }
        //check ajax call
        if($ajax) die();
    } else {
        include_once "postuser.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if any js conflicts in console. May be cache or optimisation plugins issues

Comment: @lakshmanrajput yes, finally i realized it caused by a plugin named WP Admin Hide Other's Posts. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if any js errors in console. May be cache or optimisation plugins issues

Comment: it turns out that every time i try to custom wp_query it will filtered like i am at admin page. Even there is if(is_admin) when i filter the query. Can you help me?
this will only applied for non admin. When logged in as admin everything normal.

Answer (score 0):

Then I realized that the problem is when we call ajax in wordpress it always fire on is_admin. So wherever you try to use ajax it always applied like on admin side.